# How to permit securely Bob to read some file in /var/log/?

Tags: linux, centos, user-permissions

this is **my first question** here.

I'm using a Centos server.

I want to know how to permit **proprely** a non-sudoer user (let's call it Bob) to read a specific file in /var/log. I want to be able to read some logs without being root and without jeoparadizing my logfile.

For the moment,

- I created a group named "loggers"
- I added Bob to the group
- I made a chgrp for the file I want to read with Bob
- I changed file permissions from 600 to 640.

Is there any better (secure) way to make the same thing ?

Comment: I answered a similar question here http://serverfault.com/questions/258827/what-is-the-most-secure-way-to-allow-a-user-read-access-to-a-log-file/780226#780226

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're happy with a special group, then that is the way to do it. The alternative is to use ACLs, which are additive to standard unix permissions.  You'd return your logfile to its original unix permissions then permit Bob with something like

```
setfacl -m user:Bob:r-- /var/log/mylogfile.log
```

There are circumstances where ACLs are unfavorable, in particular where you have file backup/migration across servers or filesystems. However, this isn't the case for your scenario.

Comment: They can be but it is less straightforward when you migrate files across machines because ACL data is known to the OS but not the file. For example, tar-ing a directory will not preserve it's ACLs. The solution is to export ACL permissions before moving files then reload them on the target machine (and there are easy ways of doing this). Not a big deal if everything is automated, as in a backup scenario, but it is one more thing that you need to keep in mind

Comment: ok, thanks Gavin !